# Какой тип переменной надо использовать в счетчике цикла и объявлении массива?

Tags: типы-данных, любой-язык

Попробую пояснить.

В любом языке программирования всегда все борятся за то, чтобы программа кушала как можно меньше памяти. Как бы не было утечки. Особенно в C++ нужно корректно выделять, освобождать.

Каждый тип данных занимает сколько-то места в памяти в байтах.

Примеры буду писать на C#

Объясните мне пожалуйста. Почему программисты, зная, например, что в цикле будет пробегаться по массиву длиной 10 символов и эта длина будет константна, то все равно пишут

```
for (int i = 0; i < someVar.Length; i++) { 
// do something
}
```

Почему счетчик типа `int`? Почему не `sbyte` или `byte`?
Да, может она отработает быстро в данной области видимости. Но таких блоков много же по коду.

Аналогично с массивами. 
Зная точно длину (**Поправочка. Т.к. ответы уже есть, а вопрос был задан...немного сбил с толку... : не длину, кончено же, а точно зная максимальные числа.. к примеру что будут числа  от 1 до 100** ). Все равно зачастую все объявляют

```
int[] arr = new int[8];
```

вместо

```
ushort[] arr = new ushort[8];
```

или

```
byte[] arr = new byte[8];
```

Данный массив будет же занимать память уже пока его не убьют или программа не закончит работу.

Так отсюда вопрос. Почему так все делают? Я чего-то не знаю еще пока или это просто лень программисткая?

Comment: 1) `for (int i = 0; i < someVar.Length; i++) {...}` - Length - это int же? почему тогда я должен использовать меньший тип данных? А если там завтра вдруг окажется больше элементов, чем я думал? Потом менять это в куче мест? А оно мне надо? 2) *Да, может она отработает быстро в данной области видимости. Но таких блоков много же по коду.* - это не то место, где надо оптимизировать 3) `ushort[] arr = new ushort[8];` - а разве так вы не меняете смысл исходного массива? У вас был массив int, а стал массив ushort. Здесь же не в длине массива дело, а в его значениях

Comment: _В любом языке программирования всегда все борятся за то, чтобы программа кушала как можно меньше памяти._ — это уже давно не так. Современные программы предпочитают расходовать больше памяти, чтобы ускорить вычисления. Любой кэш есть контрпример к вашему утверждению.

Comment: К тому же, программист скорее всего воспользуется foreach-ем

Comment: @danpetruk зачем же юзать форич, когда размерность известна? зачем накладные расходы на получение енумераторов и тд?

Comment: @Dmitry: Лёгкость поддержки кода и очевидное отсутствие ошибок перекрывают с лихвой расходы на один несчастный итератор. Который, кстати, скорее всего будет всё равно выкинут оптимизатором.

Comment: @BOPOH Я немного, видимо, поспешил, описывая что-то с массивами. В голове каша. Я  конечно имел в виду не длину, а то, что если я в массиве буду хранить только малые числа, грубо говоря, 1, 2,3,4,5, не доходя до 128... то вот в данном случае почему `int`, a не `byte`.  А пока читаю ответы ниже

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, в массивах используют наименьший необходимый тип данных, если хватает `byte`, то по правилам объявят как `byte`, а не `int`. Исключения часто можно увидеть, когда пример учебный или программка маленькая и тип данных не критичен.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ваше основное предположение — экономия памяти любой ценой — неверно.

Например, процессор намного более эффективно работает с типом данных `int`, чем с `byte`, поэтому для ускорения работы программисты и компилятор используют `int` где только возможно, пренебрегая мелкими потерями в памяти и выигрывая в производительности. Точно так же обычно используется тип данных `double` вместо `float` потому, что он работает быстрее, хоть и занимает вдвое больше места.

Затем, выравнивание структур данных. Компиляторы вставляют дополнительные байты между полями структур данных для выравнивания и тем самым более быстрого доступа.

Ещё пример — loop unrolling и function inlining. Оптимизирующий компилятор разворачивает цикл

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) f(i);
```

в

```
f(0); f(1); f(2); f(3); f(4); f(5); f(6); f(7); f(8); f(9);
```

потому что это быстрее. Выигрыш в три байта никому не нужен, выигрыш в три миллисекунды ощущает любой.

---

Далее, по поводу цикла. В современном программировании код должен быть достаточно общим, чтобы не акцентировать низкоуровневые оптимизации, а делать акцент на семантику, смысл кода. Поэтому низкоуровневые детали стараются прятать где только возможно.

С этой точки зрения та деталь, что данные массив имеет конкретно 10 элементов, и для его индексации можно было бы использовать 4 бита (экономия!), просто игнорируется. Кроме того. возможность индексации «узким» типом данных не проверяема компилятором, а значит, если завтра этот код получит на вход массив с бОльшим количеством элементов, код молча перестанет работать.

Правильный современный подход к перебору элементов массива таков:

```
foreach (var item in array)
{
    // process item
}
```

Здесь мы абстрагируемся от размера массива (будет работать с любым размером), от конкретного способа перебора (мы не кодируем явно порядок перебора элементов), от самого массива (тот же код сработает и со списком), таким образом перекладываем заботу о низкоуровневым оптимизациях на компилятор, и делаем код более простым в поддержке.

---

Не стоит делать простые, тривиальные вещи сложно. Оставьте мощь вашего мыслительного процесса для реально сложных задач и для алгоритмической оптимизации. Пусть за вас оптимизирует компилятор, поверьте, он умеет это лучше.

Comment: я не был бы столь категоричен и рассмотрел вариант со случайным доступом по индексам массива, когда массив `char[]` полностью помещается в кэш, а массив `int[]` (он же в 4 раза больше) уже нет. Разница может быть в разы. При последовательном доступе это может не так ощущаться из-за предвыборки данных. Но, практически в любом случае (imho) (в Си коде на современном Intel) char (если нет дополнительных алгоритмических затрат)  будет не медленнее int-а.

Comment: @avp: Это да, но я бы сделал более акцент на maintainability. Не дело экономить там, где необходимость экономии не показал профайлер. Думаю, что использование char превращается в int компилятором на достаточно хороших настройках оптимизации.

Comment: Вряд ли компилятором (по крайней мере Си). Вообще-то преобразование (в long) естественным образом происходит при загрузке данных в регистр.

Comment: @avp: А это недолго и проверить. Сейчас сделаю.

Comment: Ну, массив char-ов в массив int-ов он точно не будет переводить. А переменные типа char в стеке может и выровнять на границу слова. (сейчас посмотрю).

Comment: @avp: Хе! У меня gcc развернул цикл, чтобы сравнивать с нулём

Comment: @avp: `for (unsigned char i = 0; i < 7; i++) ...` превратилось в `movl $7, %ebx; ... subb $1, $bl; jne L2;`. То есть частично байт, частично long.

Comment: У меня в gcc `char a, b, c;` лежат в соседних байтах (независимо от уровня оптимизации). Печатал адреса из отдельно скомпилированного .o

Comment: @avp: А у меня MSVC заменил на long (регистр ESI): http://pastebin.com/Lv8qQHXF (и тоже развернул цикл).

Comment: Что-то там (в пасте) пусто. Но мы ведь начали-то про другое. Большие массивы и кэш. А как счетчики циклов ложатся по регистрам это да, микроопимизация, скорее академический интерес. (уже не пусто, увидел ассемблер)

Comment: А imho не разворачивал -- вот `jne SHORT $LL3@main` последняя команда цикла на 7 итераций. (впрочем, это совсем не важно)

Comment: Про большие массивы — тут бесспорно вы правы, я скорее про микрооптимизации, о которых и первая часть вопроса.

Comment: @avp: Я имел в виду разворот направления счётчика — от 7 к 0, а не наоборот, как закодировано. А так видно: http://i.stack.imgur.com/rHiOF.png ?

Comment: Видно. И первая ссылка тоже наполнилась кодом. Я почему-то, когда говорят о развороте цикла, представляю unroll (т.е. код цикла  заменяется повторениями его тела)

Comment: @avp: Угу, вы правы, я неправильно выразился. У меня gcc развернул в смысле unroll на 4-х итерациях. А в смысле направления изменения всегда, когда не unroll'ит.

Answer (score 5):

Объявлять в этом цикле

```
for (int i = 0; i < someVar.Length; i++) { 
// do something
}
```

переменную `i`, как имеющую тип, например, `byte`  не имеет никакого смысла, так как в данном условии

```
i < someVar.Length
```

она будет преобразована к типу `int`. То есть при генерации объектного кода будут добавлены дополнительные команды. Более того эта переменная локальная и большого влияние на использование памяти не оказывает.

Что касается массивов, то обычно объявляют массив того типа, объекты которого требуются. Не всегда заранее можно сказать, какое будет верхнее и нижнее значения элементов массива.

Если же вы точно знаете, что вас устраивает массив типа `byte`, то вы можете определить массив такого типа. Однако, опять-таки, в различных арифметических и других операциях объекты вашего массива будут постоянно преобразовываться к типу `int`.

Есть и другие связанные с этим проблемы. Например, в C++ вы можете объявить массив, имеющий тип `int8_t`. Однако этот тип является алиасом для типа `char`. Тогда при выводе элементов такого массива на консоль, используя оператор operator << у вас возникнут трудности, так как этот оператор будет пытаться выводить целые значения как символы. Например, Если вы объявили массив

```
int8_t a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
```

то при выводе его на консоль

```
for ( int8_t x : a ) std::cout << x;
```

на экране консоли появятся странные знаки, или же при выводе числа 9 вообще ничего не появится, а курсор перескочит на несколько позиций вперед, так как значение 9 будет рассматриваться оператором вывода как символ табуляции.

Поэтому вам придется постоянно помнить, что вместо вышеуказанного предложения вам надо писать

```
for ( int x : a ) std::cout << x;
      ^^^^
```

Это все лишь может служить источником трудно находимых ошибок.

Вот еще один пример на C++, который может привести к ошибке. Допустим у вас есть следующие объявления

```
unsigned short a = 5; 
unsigned short b = 10; 

std::cout << a - b << std::endl; 

unsigned int x = 5; 
unsigned int y = 10; 

std::cout << x - y << std::endl;
```

Как видите, все переменные имеют беззнаковый целочисленный тип и одни и те же значения. Спрашивается, будет ли вывод на консоль у двух операторов вывода

```
std::cout << a - b << std::endl; 
std::cout << x - y << std::endl;
```

одинаков?:) Проверьте это сами.:)

Есть дилемма: больше памяти - больше скорость выполнения, меньше памяти - меньше скорость выполнения.

Вы можете оптимизировать свою программу, исходя из тех критериев, которые для вас приоритетны.

Но заниматься оптимизацией надо тогда, когда вы точно знаете причину и место неудовлетворительной работы программы.

Comment: `Есть дилемма: больше памяти - больше скорость выполнения, меньше памяти - меньше скорость выполнения.` -- далеко не всегда. См. мой комментарий к ответу @VladD

Comment: @avp Это всегда так и безусловно, потому что по крайней мере вы, имея  больше памяти, можете использовать код, который был написан для меньшей памяти. Обратное же неверно.:)

Comment: А, Вы в этом смысле (количество *доступной памяти* (или даже установленной в комп)). Я имел в виду память занятую переменными в программе.

Answer (score 3):

Про оптимизацию на спичках.

В выражении `for (int i = 0; i < someVar.Length; i++) { ... }` происходит единичное выделение памяти и единичное освобождение после выхода. Даже если таких блоков много, каждый раз вы получите единичное выделение и освобождение. Дело меняется, только если у Вас есть вложенные циклы, но и данном случае речь идет о единичных выделениях, которые сразу же освобождаются. В итоге ваша программа в любой момент времени на таких блоках, сколько бы их ни было,  будет экономить в среднем 4-7 байта(12-21 в случае с двумя-тремя вложенными циклами) и терять кучу производительности. Ответьте себе на вопрос, с учетом вышесказанного, так ли важны для программы эти пару байтов?

В массивах не путайте их длину и их хранимый тип данных. В длину в квадратных скобках передают int и она опять же является единичным выделением памяти, а тип массива определяют именно исходя из хранящихся в нем данных(`Int16`, `Int32`, `Int64`). Хотя если данных не много и памяти точно хватит, иногда можно и пренебречь поставив обычный `Int32`.

В любом случае в Вашей программе наверняка найдется куча других мест, которые гораздо критичнее с точки зрения выделения памяти и скорости, чем выше приведенные.

Answer (score 0):

массив содержит значинеия типа int

```
int[] arr = new int[8];
```

массив содержит значения uint16

```
ushort[] arr = new ushort[8];
```

массив содержит значения типа byte

```
byte[] arr = new byte[8];
```

Вы превели некорректные примеры.
И как правильно заметил @BOPOH размерность `Length` это `int`, а есть еще `LongLength`, который размера `long` или `int64`